# How to copy ULONG into PUCHAR

Tags: c, visual-studio, unsigned-char

Today I am trying to copy a `unsigned long` variable into the contents of an `unsigned char *` variable.

The reasoning for this is, I wrote an RC4 cipher which requires the key input to be a `unsigned char *`, I am using the `SYSTEMTIME` class to obtain a value & combining it with a randomly generated `long` value to obtain my key for RC4 - I am using it as a timestamp for a user created account to mark in my sqlite dbs.

Anyways, the problem I ran into is that I cannot copy the `ULONG` into `PUCHAR`.

I've tried

`wsprintfA(reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(ucVar), "%lu", ulVar);`

and I've tried

`wsprintfA((LPSTR)ucVar, "%lu", ulVar);`

However, after executing my program the result in `ucVar` is just empty, or it doesn't even compute, and crashing the application.

**[edit 1]**

I thought maybe the `memcpy` approach would work, so I tried declaring another variable and moving it into `ucVar`, but it still crashed the application - i.e. It didn't reach the `MessageBox()`:

```
unsigned char *ucVar;
char tmp[64]; // since ulVar will never be bigger than 63 character + 1 for '\0'

wsprintfA(tmp, "%lu", ulVar);
memcpy(ucVar, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
MessageBox(0, (LPSTR)ucVar, "ucVar", 0);
```

**[/edit 1]**

**[edit 2]**

HeapAlloc() on ucVar with of size 64 fixed my problem, thank you ehnz for your suggestion!

**[/edit 2]**

Can anyone give me some approach to this problem? It is greatly appreciated!

Regards,
  Andrew

Comment: How is `ucVar` allocated?

Comment: It isn't allocated. It is simply declared `unsigned char *ucVar;

Comment: @AndrewPeters - It has to 'own' some memory. At present `ucVar` is able to store the address of some memory, but unless it points to valid memory, trying to sprintf into the location it points to will result in tears. Think about it like property - if you have a piece of paper with an address on it, you can drive to that location and dump whatever you like on the front lawn. Problem is, if you dont own the property whose address is recorded, you'll get a "WTF are you doing?" exception from the homeowner.

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for the analogy. So what you're saying is, I should use `HeapAlloc()` to set the size of the `ucVar` or what?

Comment: @AndrewPeters - you're welcome. Yes, you should allocate some memory via malloc, calloc or HeapAlloc. Once this is done, the memcpy in your added code-block will function.

Comment: I added your suggestion to the code & now it works. Can you please answer the question with your suggestions so that I can give you the tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have ownership of memory you're trying to use, all kinds of things can happen. These may range from the error going unnoticed because nothing else already owns that memory, to an instant crash, to a value that disappears because something else overwrites the memory between the time that you set it and the time that you attempt to retrieve a value from it.

Fairly fundamental concepts when dealing with dynamic memory allocation, but quite the trap for the uninitiated.